# Postgres how do I remove an index on a chilldtable in a partition?

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I want to disable an index on a sub partition table. When I try, I get an error.

```
ERROR: cannot drop index mysema.col_extra_val_355_customer_id_idx because index mysema.col_extra_val_customer_id_idx1 requires it HINT: You can drop index mysema.col_extra_val_customer_id_idx1 instead.
```

The table is a huge table, that is partitioned with 1/2 billion rows. When inserting new data, having indexes causes a slow insert. The inserts is clustered for a sub partition table each time. To increase the insert speed, I woluld like to remove the index for that table and then reinstall the index.

Removing the index in the full table will take too much time, as there is 1/2 of billion rows. I use Postgres 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detach the partition, drop the index, load into the partition, re-create the index and re-attach the partition.

Of course that only works well if you don't need the partition attached while you are loading.

Comment: Thank you. I have just tested with the table. Detached a partition from the table. The partition contained 3,2 mill rows. It took.153 ms. From there I dropped the index, did the inserts, restablished the index and re-attached again in 413 ms.